# DataTable Layout is working but it does not do any other stuff like searching , sorting etc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have used Datatables to make my generic table look good. It has started working accurately like showing how many pages to show and a search box. But It does not do any functionality like search or pagination.

Here is my code

```
<?php include 'db.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            "info": false
        } );

        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable" width="99.8%" class="order-column table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Subject</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM hr;";
        $result  = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    $id = $row['hr_id']; 
                    $timestamp = $row['timeSent'];
                    $date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($timestamp));
                    $time = date('H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp)); ?>
                    <td><?php echo $date;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $time;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
                    <td><?php 
                    $cat =  $row['category_id'];
                    if($cat == 1){
                        echo "Suggestion";
                    }
                    elseif ($cat == 2) {
                        echo "Claim";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Help";
                    }?></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" <?php echo "href='HrThread.php?id=$id'" ?> >See More</a></td>     
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Data fetching is working fine. The table is looking fine also.  The only thing that i want is for it to work properly like a datatable should.

Comment: check console for any js related error.

Comment: if this line hasn't any syntax error? line
```<td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" <?php echo "href='HrThread.php?id=$id'" ?> >See More</a></td>```

I think it should be like this 
```<td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" <?php echo "href='HrThread.php?id=$id'" ?>See More</a></td>```

Comment: otherwise, there must be a console error in your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of your `script` tags and `link` tags and moved them around a little and changed your code to:

```
<?php include 'db.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable" width="99.8%" class="order-column table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Subject</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM hr;";
        $result  = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    $id = $row['hr_id']; 
                    $timestamp = $row['timeSent'];
                    $date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($timestamp));
                    $time = date('H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp)); ?>
                    <td><?php echo $date;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $time;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
                    <td><?php 
                    $cat =  $row['category_id'];
                    if($cat == 1){
                        echo "Suggestion";
                    }
                    elseif ($cat == 2) {
                        echo "Claim";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Help";
                    }?></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" <?php echo "href='HrThread.php?id=$id'" ?> >See More</a></td>     
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            "info": false
        } );

        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try changing your code to this. I don't have the data to populate the table but this seemed to make pagination and the search functionality and everything a dataTable is supposed to do appear to work for me.

Comment: Nope. Same output

Comment: @FaizanAhmad what browser and version are you using?

Comment: Chrome. Version 77

Comment: I'm using chrome version 77 as well. Try this, take the code I posted and paste it into a .html file and open only that file in chrome. Let me know if you see the dataTable items then. If you can see everything you're looking for then the problem isn't this code. Its embedded somewhere else.

Comment: @FaizanAhmad did doing that help any?

Comment: It works on static data.. But as soon i put a generic data in it from database it does not work.

Comment: Maybe its the way the data is being inserted into the table? Does the data look correct when generic data is added to the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200663/discussion-between-faizan-ahmad-and-king11).